# bcm4331 (wifi) doesn't work on FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, macbook-pro, freebsd, broadcom

I've installed FreeBSD 10.1 on my MacBook Pro Mid 2012 (MacBook Pro 9.2). Everything works pretty good, except Wifi interface (`bcm4331`).

FreeBSD has two modules - [`bwi-firmware-kmod`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bwi&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) and [`bwn-firmware-kmod`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bwn&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) for Broadcom devices. According to their `man` pages, both of them don't support `bcm4331` device.

Okay, we can think that FreeBSD doesn't support `bcm4331`, at least yet. But tonight I've looked into `bwn-firmware-kmod` and `bwi-firmware-kmod` makefiles, and found that they use [`b43-fwcutter`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=b43-fwcutter&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports). You can find Makefile for `bwn-firmware-kmod` [here](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/net/bwn-firmware-kmod/Makefile?view=markup).

It is an utility to extract firmware from proprietary drivers. When we install `bwn-firmware-kmod` from ports, he's makefiles downloads proprietary driver from http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/, extracts firmware from there using `b43-fwcutter` and builds module using this firmwares.

So the problem is quit simple, `bwn-firmware-kmod`'s makefile downloads `broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2` and works with it.

I've found that Linux supports `bcm4331` devices, and I've tested it under Ubuntu 14.04. It works perfect there. Here is some instruction about how to get this device working in Linux using `b43-fwcutter`: http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Other_distributions_not_mentioned_above.

So I think I have to download some another version of proprietary driver, extract firmware from there and use it with `bwn-firmware-kmod`. But I even don't know if I am right or not in my theories. If I'm right, then I can continue to research source codes, and try to support `bcm4331` by myself.

Is there anybody who can help me to make `bcm4331` working under FreeBSD 10.1?

Comment: Okay, my BCM4331 works perfect via `ndis`.

Comment: If you can answer your own question, with a link and a little detail, I'll be grateful. (At https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ndis%20PC-BSD the top hit is [NDIS support - PC-BSD Forums](https://forums.pcbsd.org/showthread.php?t=445) but that topic no longer exists.)

Comment: I found [NDIS support](https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-422.html) at its new URL; the topic ran from 2005 to 2009. Today in [PC-BSD Testing]: [PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENT and Wi-Fi: how to drive Broadcom BCM4331 in a MacBookPro8, 2?](http://lists.pcbsd.org/pipermail/testing/2016-March/010462.html)