# BCM4331 Installation issues on FreeBSD 10.2

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, kernel, freebsd, broadcom

I have been unable to find the 'right' 64-bit XP drivers to use ndisgen to create a working module -- I can get it to recognize the card but it has exit errors there are always  IRQ and memory leak errors  ---any help would be appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Possible relevant link: 
http://superuser.com/questions/869641/bcm4331-wifi-doesnt-work-on-freebsd-10-1

Comment: Landon Fuller has been working on a BCM4331 driver at https://github.com/landonf/freebsd/tree/user/landonf/bcm4331-CURRENT But I don't know what state his driver is in